# Unable to update Ubuntu server due to unmet dependensies

Tags: apt, dependencies

When I am trying to install system update on my Ubuntu Server 13.04 AMD64 it returns the following message:

Now updating apparmor ..

```
Installing package(s) with command apt-get -y install apparmor ..

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.44.53); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.53.63.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.44.53); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.53.63.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.53.63 is to be installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.53.63 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

.. install failed!
```

I Have tried all the common things listed in the article below, but it still gives the same message.
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-deo-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Hi, here is the output of that command:

```
sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.53.63 is installed
                Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.44.53) but 3.2.0.53.63 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.


> sudo apt-get -qq update && apt-cache policy linux-server
linux-server:
  Installed: 3.2.0.44.53
  Candidate: 3.2.0.53.63
  Version table:
     3.2.0.53.63 0
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.2.0.44.53 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.0.23.25 0
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

rgds
E Andersen

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the metapackages has some dependency issues, remove it and install it again, then upgrade your system as usual:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove linux-server
sudo apt-get install linux-server
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following worked for me:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```